# How do I sign in to google without compromising password?

Tags: google-play-store, security, password, daydream

I've got a Lenovo Solo VR headset. I've got a long, randomly generated password for my google account that is pretty much impossible to memorize without an eidetic memory. If you remove the goggles to look up the next few characters, the login process resets (this is pretty much the exact same problem on Android phones where switching apps to copy the password restarts the login process). It goes without saying that trying to type this in using the simple hand controller is a PITA (possible, but not fun). In order to use the Google Store, I changed my Google password to something far simpler (as simple as possible). Great, now I'm able to login, but when I change my password back to a long, complex, random password, Google Store kicks me out.

Other than creating a separate google account with a simple, easy-to-type password just for my VR goggles, is there any way to login to Google without a password? Or not have it log me out when I change my password?

If anybody from Google reads this, it would be great if Android or, at least, Daydream could just do what a bunch of other apps do and show me a short code in the headset, then I can visit a page on my computer where I log in as the account I want to activate and then type in the code.

Comment: Have you tried setting up 2FA for your account? That's how I ideally  use my Google account. A simple password + the 6-digit 2FA which is either a text/SMS OTP on the phone or a OTP generated by the authenticator app.

Comment: Yes, I use 2FA, but I still prefer the more complex password.